# Deshabilitar log para archivos específicos dentro de bloque location en un reverse proxy

Tags: linux, nginx

Tengo un nginx/1.13.9 en Debian funcionando como proxy en reversa con una configuración similar a la siguiente:

```
server {
    server_name dominio.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://upstream1;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /location2/ {
      proxy_pass http://upstream2/otrodirectorio;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }

}
```

Quiero introducir las siguientes reglas para todos los archivos de imágenes y js:

```
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
```

Ahora, usando un bloque location de la siguiente forma deshabilita el log para todos los archivos pero envía todos los requests a `upstream1`:

```
location ~/*\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|xls|pdf|mp3|ico|JPG)$ {
    proxy_pass http://upstream1;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
```

Tratar de insertar una regla **dentro** del bloque `location2` deshabilita el log pero envía las peticiones a `http://upstream2/` en lugar de `http://upstream2/otrodirectorio/` ya sea con una referencia directa o usando regex:

```
location /location2/ {
    location /location2/css/ui.css {
            //todos mis intentos resultan en 404 not found.
            access_log off;
    }
 ...
```

Dicho todo esto, ¿cuál es la manera correcta de hacerlo?
Trato de servir los archivos de forma regular pero quiero deshabilitar el log para este tipo de archivos solamente.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente lo que se tiene que hacer es un rewrite; se captura la parte que debe permanecer en nuestro request hacia el proxy y se agrega en el URL nuevo como `$1` (note la opción `break` para que se tome en cuenta el primer match), posteriormente se pasa este request al proxy con `proxy_pass`. Todo esto en un bloque `location` anidado en `/location2/`:

```
location /location2/ {

    location ~* .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|js|css)$ {
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
      rewrite ^/location2/(.*)$ /otrodirectorio/$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://10.49.28.9;
    }
```

Con esto se resuelve el problema y se puede configurar cualquier bloque.

Comment: https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/mobile/000/023/397/C-658VsXoAo3ovC.jpg

Comment: Encontré la solución después de un rato, tenía que cerrar mi propia pregunta dado que nadie la había tomado hasta ese momento.